# Session Variables Not Sticking

Tags: php, session, authentication

**I'm sorry guys -- after two hours of looking and commenting out and so on, I found one tiny include that was referencing a redirected domain. Somehow this threw everything else off. I'm still not sure why, but by fixing that file to the new domain I was able to fix it. Again, thanks for your help and time in replying to me!**

I'm fairly familiar with sessions in PHP, yet I can't tell why these session variables are not sticking on this login system I have. When I log in, I get successfully sent to the index page, but any pages therein I get kicked back to the login page, and also when I reload the index page. I have echoed the session variable $_SESSION['login'] on the index page to make sure its value has accurately been carried over, and it's *is* there..

... code removed

Comment: @tradyblix Sorry for not specifying - Linux, PHP Version 5.2.17, session support enabled...

Comment: how do you access the file in the original folder and on the one level up folder?

Answer (score 1):

My wild guess but usually a problem I always encounter in Apache under Linux when dealing with sessions.

Check `session.save_path` in php.ini. If there's a path there and doesn't exist in your system, create it e.g. `session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/session"`. I'm guessing PHP cannot create session files and thus session won't persist across pages. Give the folder a write permission too, try `0777` (but it's not the best permission as it allows all users). HTH!

Comment: I don't run the server (it's on hosting) or anything, but there *is* a value for session.save_path, "/tmp". Also, I have no problems with sessions on any other pages. On the same server, there's a similar  large but separate login system which has no problem. :/

Comment: Another idea (sorry to bug you) - does that save_path have to be absolute somehow?

Comment: preferably yes, it'll be a pain to give it `../../../path` kinda of location. it varies on different systems too so it can go crazy. it's easier to start on root `/` and lead to the save path.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you destroying the session during login? This is probably a reason.

```
session_start();
session_unregister('login');
session_write_close();
session_start();
session_destroy();
```

You probably might just call session_start() and clear 'login' session value:

```
<?
$ERRBG="";
$ERRMSG="";
session_start();
$_SESSION['login'] = null;
require_once("db/mysql_connect.php");
.......
```

Comment: I wiped out all that destroying and so on, and replaced with your code. The result is the same - still getting sent back to login when I try to go to another page or reload.

Answer (score 0):

Use session_start() only once in the php page at the starting

Do not use session_destroy().
If you want to remove session variable, use `unset` function.
In case if you want to remove all the variables use `session_unset` function

Use session_destroy() as the logout operation

Answer (score 0):

Please do this step :

1. use session_start() at the top of page after `<?php` just once .
2. don't destroy session
3. write var_dump($_SESSION) on in your test-index and write it in that
   page when you click on it , it's
   redirect to login page ( insert
   die() after it ) !

I think session start in your test-index but not in your other page

report result to me !